# how to exclude snapshots while running tar in Solaris

Tags: solaris, tar

I'm trying to take a tar of the '/home/store/' directory content.

```
tar cvf store.tar /home/store/
```

While doing so, I can see that the **.snapshot** directories are also getting included. My understanding is that snapshots are kind of backups. Can I skip this? If possible, how? Tried excluding a **test** directory using the below command ran from /home/store/

```
tar cvfX store.tar <(echo /home/store/test) /home/store/
```

But this is not excluding the test directory from the tar created.

Also, tried this

```
tar cvf store.tar /home/store/ --exclude-file=exclude.txt
```

Output:

`a /home/store// 0K 
a /home/store//.profile 1K 
a /home/store//local.profile 1K 
a /home/store//.vas_logon_server 1K 
a /home/store//.vas_disauthcc_611400381 1K 
a /home/store//.bash_history 7K 
a /home/store//test/ 0K 
a /home/store//test/1.txt 1K 
a /home/store//test/migrate-perf3.txt 3958K 
a /home/store//test.txt 1K 
a /home/store//exclude.txt 1K 
a /home/store//.snapshot/hourly.0/d2/dd/d5d/f82-1 59K 
a /home/store//.snapshot/hourly.0/d2/dd/d5d/f83-1 58K 
.....
tar: --exclude-file=exclude.txt: No such file or directory`

/home/store/exclude.txt has the entry 'test'. Tried entering the following as well and got same error.

`/home/store/test/
/home/store/test/1.txt`

When I gave the full path to 'exclude.txt' like this

```
`tar cvf store.tar /home/store/ --exclude-file=/home/store/exclude.txt`
```

it's giving the below error

`tar: can't change directories to --exclude-file=/home/store: No such file or directory`

tar -h

`Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x}[BDeEFhilmnopPqTvw@[0-7]][bfk][X...] [blocksize] [tarfile] [size] [exclude-file...] {file | -I include-file | -C directory file}...`

Thanks well in advance! 
Van Peer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do so:

tar cvfX /var/tmp/src.tar /var/tmp/excl.txt /var/tmp/src/

Your exclude file should contain path:

/home/store//.snapshot

Best practice not to use full path of your tar dir, because in future you can overwite your /etc , when extract tar archive from /var/tmp, for example.

Comment: was entering /home/store/test in exclude.txt! Changed it to /home/store//test and it worked! Thanks @igoska! Is it safe to ignore .snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
sudo tar -zcvpf /backup/farm-backup-$(date +%d-%m-%Y).tar.gz  --exclude ".snapshots" --exclude ".cache"  farm
```

Did not use a backslash in the command ie:`/farm` for the directory. Execute the tar command from the `/home` directory to back up "farm"  user.

for making a backup in  the root `/backup` directory.

OS: OpenSuse 15.1

Comment: OS: OpenSuse 15.1?? The question has **"while running tar in Solaris"** in its title.  Options such as `--exclude` are GNU-specific extensions not available on other operating systems.