# query on tar and .snapshot directories

Tags: solaris, tar, snapshot, nas

We've content which amounts to 110GB on NAS. While running tar to copy this to use in a different location, by default the ".snapshot" directories were also getting included. The corresponding tar file size way exceeded the 100GB; had to interrupt the tar command when the size reached 140GB.

Solaris 10.

Can we exclude these directories? What are the implications?

Regards, 
Van

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to exclude snapshots while running tar in Solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035988/how-to-exclude-snapshots-while-running-tar-in-solaris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this would be simple, but it took a while to come up with a (messy) solution:

cd tarsource_dir

find ./.snapshot > exclude-files

tar cvfX /tmp/blob.tar ./exclude-file .

...

./.snapshot excluded

...

Hope this at least gives some ideas!

Comment: Thanks Noj! My question is whether we can exclude these .snapshot directories and the implications of excluding. Got the answer on how to exclude in a separate post. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: that would exclude the .snapshot directory (slightly modified find would catch them all!), or am I missing the point here :-) Can you share your alternate solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46037420/1836483 I understand that it can be excluded. My question is whether it's safe to exclude or not. What impact does it have?

Comment: OK I get you! Sorry I missed the whole point of your question! As I understand it the .zfs/snapshot directories contain the original copies of files that have changed since the snapshot time. For a tar "backup" they would not be required, assuming you created a new ZFS FS and untarred into it, it would have no memory of previous snapshots so they would be simply taking up space!

Comment: Will try excluding and see how it goes @Noj, thank you!